# Website very narrow on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

For some reason I can't seem to find help on this from searching the internet... perhaps I'm not wording it well.

I've had this problem come up previously, but for right now it's on this website:

http://merchantbankingresources.com/

You can see in the screenshot that the website is pushed to the left and very narrow. It's on an iPhone 4s.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The proper sizing of the page is controlled by the `viewport` meta property. Adding something as below to your website's head would scale your website automatically to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

After putting it in, you can make your page occupy whole page with `width:100%;`.

**EDIT-** The `<ul>` in your `gform` is actually causing the problem. It is rendering to a wrong position.

**EDIT-** Change the `.gform_body` css. It gives it a `left` of 500px

Comment: Thanks for your answer; unfortunately that is already added to the page. And this was definitely the first thing I looked for.

Comment: I re-edited it. There was a mistake in previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code in the `HEAD`

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a classic case of the html, body not wanting to stretch, but the issue lies within the page itself.